# Django 1.10 issue with python-social-auth

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am trying to use django-social-auth in one of my project.
However migrate command ends with this error:

```
class JSONField(six.with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.TextField)):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, django-social-auth does not work with Django 1.10 since it's deprecated for two years now. You can fork it and fix it yourself, or change your social auth module to [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) which is the recommended replacement for the django-social-auth module.

Comment: @blacklwhite Seems it does. Upgraded it and now its working.

Comment: Ok. I somehow had in mind that I needed to change to pyhton-social-auth for exactly the same reason – might have been another project :) If you have some time, it's still worth to migrate to the newer one since it's still maintained.

Answer (score 0):

[django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) is a DEPRECATED variant now, the link describes as,

```
NOTE: THIS LIBRARY IS DEPRECATED IN FAVOR OF python-social-auth.  
RIGHT NOW THIS LIBRARY DEPENDS DIRECTLY ON python-social-auth AND  
SHOULD BE  CONSIDERED AS A MIGRATION STEP
```

Use [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth), there is a [section](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html) on how to integrate `python-social-auth` with `django-social-auth`, it is recommended if you want to use the code in production.